# Error after add firebase plugin in my project

Tags: firebase, nativescript-angular

I am add firebase plugin in my nativescript angular project and then run the project it show's the error below:

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:17:2-38:16 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below code in your project app.gradle file.

Like:- **App_resources -> Android -> app.gradle.**

**Code:-**

```
configurations.all { 
 resolutionStrategy { 
   force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0' 
   force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0' 
   force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9' 
   force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0' 
 }
}
```